# separate between rows

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (id int, [name] varchar(100), category_sort varchar(100));
INSERT @yourtable VALUES
(1, 'Campaign1','Beverage'),
(2, 'Campaign2','Beverage'),
(3, 'Campaign3','Food'),
(4, 'Campaign4','Beverage'),
(5, 'Campaign5','Hot Drinks'),
(6, 'Campaign6','Advertizing'),
(7, 'Campaign7','Marketing');

WITH x AS
(
SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category_sort ORDER BY id)
FROM @yourtable
)
SELECT id, name, category_sort
FROM x
ORDER BY rn, category_sort;
```

Now when i run the above code it is return :

```
6 Campaign6 Advertizing
1 Campaign1 Beverage
3 Campaign3 Food
5 Campaign5 Hot Drinks
7 Campaign7 Marketing
2 Campaign2 Beverage
4 Campaign4 Beverage
```

But actually what i need is :

```
6 Campaign6 Advertizing
1 Campaign1 Beverage
3 Campaign3 Food
5 Campaign5 Hot Drinks
2 Campaign2 Beverage
7 Campaign7 Marketing
4 Campaign4 Beverage
```

Comment: It's unclear what determines the order in your desired results.  Why should id 2 be before 7?. Please explain the business rule in your question.

Comment: What i need exactly is:  if i have same category coming in previous row and next row, i need to put another category between them, for example, if i have beverage in row 1  and beverage in row 2 and food in row 3  so the code will put beverage then food then beverage ,  sorting is not required anything, but may be i have more than 100 records

Comment: So basically you are ok with any random ordering as long as no two consecutive rows have the same category, right? (If possible of course. If there are more than 50% of rows have the same category, it would be impossible).

Comment: The solution will vary depending on the SQL Server version you are using. Add the version-specific tag. Also, note a table is logically an unordered set of rows so concepts like previous and next will require ordering to be applied, probably on the `id` column like you did with `ROW_NUMBER`.

Comment: Interesting question. What happens when your wish for diversity among neighboors has a limit? I.e.: what happens if have 10 beverages and two foods? I've dealt with something like that in *code*, but never found a way to find a workable solution with only SQL.

Comment: I'd change the title of the Question to something like *Sort rows to avoid or minimize number of consecutive values (for a given column)*. I know I could do it myself, but I think @user129687 is better prepared than myself to know if this really summarizes his/her question.

Answer (score 1):

This will work I think:

```
WITH x AS
(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY category_sort, id) - 1,
              halfsize = (1 + COUNT(*) OVER ()) / 2
    FROM @yourtable
)
SELECT id, name, category_sort
FROM x
ORDER BY rn % halfsize, rn ;
```

Test at **[dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d4d37e720362a30c5536c45383bc891a)**:

> ```
> id | name      | category_sort
> -: | :-------- | :------------
>  6 | Campaign6 | Advertizing  
>  3 | Campaign3 | Food         
>  1 | Campaign1 | Beverage     
>  5 | Campaign5 | Hot Drinks   
>  2 | Campaign2 | Beverage     
>  7 | Campaign7 | Marketing    
>  4 | Campaign4 | Beverage
> ```

Comment: I'm afraid it does generalize: *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=35878650cfcb10e43c1e02b739580c65)*

Comment: @joanolo as I said in the question's comments, if there are more than 50% of the same category, the task is impossible. The query still spreads the rows with same category in 3 distinct islands (it could be done with 4 in the specific case but meh ;)

Comment: With 50%, there's always an answer: put the majority category in rows 1, 3, 5, ..., (2*n+1); spread all the others among the remaining positions in any random fashion. Thing becomes impossible when you have *more* than 50%. Even then, there's a way to *minimize* the number of consecutive appearances of categories. These strategies are used, for instance, when showing ads without previous knowledge of the audience: maximize diversity. I've never found a way to do it using just SQL.

Comment: this will work:                                                                                       WITH counted  AS (SELECT cnt=COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY category_sort),* FROM Category),
   numbered AS (SELECT *, mx=MAX(cnt) OVER (),rn=ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) FROM counted)

SELECT  id, [name],category_sort
FROM   numbered
ORDER BY rn%mx,cnt;